# INSERÇÃO duplicada com mysql ::PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

Alguém sabe explicar o porque que quando eu executo esse código ele INSERE duas vezes o mesmo valor na tabela?

Eu acredito que seja que esse problema acontece quando eu faço uma validação para verificar se foi inserido os valores: `if(!$lc_follow_dados->execute())`

```
        $method     = $_POST['method'];
        $id_de  = $_POST['id_de'];
        $id_para    = $_POST['id_para'];
        $f_data     = time(); 

        if($method == 'add'){
            $busca_dados_s = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `lc_follow` WHERE `f_de` = ? AND `f_para` = ?");
            $busca_dados_s->execute(array($id_de, $id_para));
            if($busca_dados_s->rowCount() == 0){
                $lc_follow_dados = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `lc_follow`(f_de,f_para,f_data)VALUES(:f_de,:f_para,:f_data)");
                $lc_follow_dados->bindValue(":f_de",$id_de);
                $lc_follow_dados->bindValue(":f_para",$id_para);
                $lc_follow_dados->bindValue(":f_data",$f_data);
                $lc_follow_dados->execute();

                if(!$lc_follow_dados->execute()) { 
                    echo '::ERRO::';
                } else {
                    echo    '<div class="but_add" onclick="functionAjax_follow(\''.$id_de.'\', \''.$id_para.'\',\'remove\')">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                Seguindo
                            </div>';
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao chamar o método `execute()` do PDO ele executa a consulta contida naquele prepared statement, no seu código tem duas chamadas. Remova a primeira ocorrência

```
 $lc_follow_dados->execute();

 if(!$lc_follow_dados->execute()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Exatamente, quando você entra no "if" ele executa novamente a sql correspondente:

- Primeira chamada : $lc_follow_dados->execute();
- Segunda Chamada : if(!$lc_follow_dados->execute())

Basta remover a primeira chamada.